# Как написать правильную генерацию атрибута for?

Tags: php, opencart, radio

Скажу сразу, что php практически не знаю, поэтому без помощи никак выполнить задачу не смогу. Работаю с модулем "Simple 4.9.4" для Opencart. На странице есть две radio-кнопки и этот кусок кода, как я понял, отвечает за их создание. На сайте уже существуют стили, которые создают radio-кнопки. Чтобы они работали input должен находиться перед label. Я добавил атрибут for для лейбла, чтобы можно было переключать кнопки. Возникла проблема, атрибут for у двух radio-кнопок одинаковый, поэтому нормально работает только одна кнопка. Как можно это исправить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($values as $info) { ?>
      <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $name ?>" id="<?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo $info['id'] ?>" <?php echo $value == $info['id'] ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> <?php echo $reload ? 'data-onchange="reloadAll"' : 'data-reload-payment-form="true"'?>>
        <label for="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $info['text'] ?></label>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: у этих кнопок одинаковый атрибут name и id, попробуйте начать с того, чтобы их изменить.

Comment: Так я и не понимаю как сделать их разными. В этом моя проблема.

Comment: Внутрь Id для поля пропишите ‘label’ . $info[‘id’]